# Different output by df and du

Tags: redhat, partition, df, du

I have an old RHEL 5.5 Box,

When I fire df -kh I see that /var is of 49 GB with 100 % usage.

But then I go inside the /var

```
cd /var
```

and I fire

```
du -kh
```

I see that only total 300 MBs are used.

I am not able to get it. Is is possible that this partition is shared with different partition?

I see that /opt is also of 49 GB. I think that they are same partition.

I need to free /var to start mysql but there is hardly anything to be deleted.

Any pointers?

Comment: What does `mount` say? Is /var a symlink to somewhere inside /opt?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo lsof +L1` in your question.

Comment: If you look over on the right of the page under **Related** - one of the Q&As there will almost certainly answer your question. My guess is that you have deleted a log file but forgotten to restart the daemon that is writing to it so the file is still occupying disk space.

Comment: Hello, welcome to serverfault, this question has already been here : serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible that youve deleted a lot of files, they arent on disk, but the process still has them open. Restart the process that you think has them open. Sometimes merely a `kill -HUP` will do it.

To find the processes that have files in this filesystem open, use `fuser -c <filesustem>` or `lsof +L1 | grep <filesystem>`